# How to check if a value is present in the list of map using Java8 Stream

Tags: list, dictionary, java-8, stream

I have the following `userList` of type `List<Map<String, Object>>` json array

```
[
  {
    "type": "OWNER",
    "address": "xxxxxxx"
  },
  {
    "type": "LOCATION",
    "address": "sssssss"
  }
  :
]
```

I want to find if the any of the map object in list contains of type value **"OWNER"** or **"ADMIN"**. I tried he below code

```
List<String> ownerList = new ArrayList<>();
ownerList.add("OWNER");
ownerList.add("ADMIN");

AtomicBoolean isUserOwner = new AtomicBoolean(false);

userList.forEach(user -> isUserOwner.set(user.entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(m -> m.getKey().contains("type"))
                    .anyMatch(map -> ownerList.contains(valueOf(map.getValue())))));

isUserOwner.get();// ---> get the boolean value which shows if it is either OWNER or ADMIN
```

The above code works fine, but can anyone please tell me if there is any other way in stream to check this efficiently

Comment: The above code works fine with the last map in the list responsible for `set`ting the value of the variable. If that's the case, you don't really need to iterate over all the `Map`s. Something like `boolean isUSerOwner = userList.get(userList.size()-1).entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(m -> m.getKey().contains("type"))
                .anyMatch(map -> ownerList.contains(String.valueOf(map.getValue())));` Additionally, `using a Set<String> ownerList` would help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to find if one of the elements is an owner or admin, you can use this:

```
boolean containsOwnerOrAdmin = users.stream()
          .map(a -> a.get("type"))
          .filter(Objects::nonNull)
          .anyMatch(type -> ("OWNER".equals(type) || "ADMIN".equals(type)));
```

This loop through each map from the list getting an item with the key "type" and will filter out any null values, then it will check if any of the resulting Objects is equal to OWNER or ADMIN.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this instead.

```java
userList.forEach(user -> isUserOwner.set(user.entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(m -> m.getKey().contains("type") && ownerList.contains(m.get("type")))
                    .findAny()
                    .isPresent()
);
```

The m.get() is safe because the RHS of the && is only evaluated if the LHS was true.

Comment: Is there any way to remove AtomicBoolean